# Accessing selectedItems from ng-grd in directive

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

Hello I have a gird with the following options:

$scope.mySourceSelections = [];

```
$scope.gridOptions = {
            data: 'formatSources',
            showSelectionCheckbox: true,
            enableCellSelection: true,
            enableRowSelection: true,
            multiSelect: false,
            selectedItems: $scope.mySourceSelections

   };
```

In my directive I have a template to embed HTML on my page. 
In my div tag I have the attribute:
`data-activity-source={{mySourceSelections}}`

When the page renders the attribute produces: 
`data-activity-source="[{"SourceName":"College of Letters & Science"}]"`

To set the source, I need the syntax to be `data-activity-source="College of Letters & Science"`.

When I change my template to be: `data-activity-source={{mySourceSelections[0].SourceName}}` 
I receive the following two errors:

```
GET /api/v1/activity/public?s=0&l=1&o=College%20of%20Letters%20&%20Science 400 (Bad Request) jquery-1.11.1.min.js?v=1412791216854:4
ERROR: getPublicActivitiesForSource : ajax : error
```

I know this is occurring when trying to access the [0] index of mySourceSelections. How do I fix this and gain access to the SourceName value of "College of Letters & Science"?

Comment: How do you want the request format to be ? Can you give an example of a desired call to your API ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the ampersand is causing problems with your GET.  Try urlencoding the request.  An ampersand is %26 so try:

```
GET /api/v1/activity/public?s=0&l=1&o=College%20of%20Letters%20%26%20Science
```